# Chrome extension auto enable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome-extension [Reddit hide username](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reddit-hide-username/hioiajpfkkcebikifclacdffngngecip). This extension hides your Reddit username when the button in popup.html is clicked.

I want to update it wherein if I visit Reddit, my extension will auto trigger and automatically do its job. How can I do that? Below here is my manifest.json and here's my [Github repository](https://github.com/thekhenzie/reddit-hide-username)

```
{
  "name": "Reddit Hide Username",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Hide your username in new Reddit UI!",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage"
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "32": "images/icon32.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "32": "images/icon32.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: You need to [declare your content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively) in manifest.json instead of using executeScript.

Comment: Woow cool. Thanks fam.